# Why does paintComponent not erase past Objects?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Im trying to make a rectangle move on certain Input. Although the Input works, the rectangle is not being redrawn in the way I want it to. The former rectangles are not being erased.

`

```
public class MiniGame_Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread gameThread;
    public KeyHandler2 keyH = new KeyHandler2();
    public MGPlayer spieler = new MGPlayer(keyH, this);
    
    public MiniGame_Panel() {
        setBackground(new Color(222, 228, 128, 0));
        setBounds(0, 0, 16*16*3 + 300 + 3, 16*13*3);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus(); 
        
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
    }

    public void startGameThread() {
        gameThread = new Thread((Runnable) this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/60;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime; 
        
        // GAME LOOP
        while(gameThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            
            if(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void update() {
        spieler.update();
    }
    
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        spieler.draw(g2);
        
        g2.dispose();
    }

}
```

```
public class MGPlayer {

    private int x, y;
    private Rectangle rect;
    private int width, height;
    private int leben;
    private KeyHandler2 keyH;
    private MiniGame_Panel mGp;
    
    public MGPlayer(KeyHandler2 keyH, MiniGame_Panel miniGame_Panel) {
        x = 10;
        y = 100;
        width = 50;
        height = 100;
        leben = 3;
        this.keyH = keyH;
        this.mGp = miniGame_Panel;
    }
    
    boolean allowJump;
    public void update() {
        if(keyH.stats) {
            if(!allowJump) {
                this.y -= 8;
            }
            //System.out.println("Leertaste");
        }
        if(keyH.left == true) {
            this.x--;
            //System.out.println("links");
        }
        if(keyH.right == true) {
            this.x++;
            //System.out.println("rechts");
            }
        
        if(y <= 200) {
            this.y++;
            allowJump = true;
        }else {
            allowJump = false;
        }
        
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
    
}
```

[image]
`

I just want to draw a rectangle that moves on certain input. This works but instead of redrawing the rectangle, they all stay in the panel.

Comment: `setBackground(new Color(222, 228, 128, 0));` <- This is why.  Swing does not support alpha based background colors, use `setOpaque` instead ... wow, second one to do this today

Comment: We should also discuss how Swing is not thread safe and that you should not be modifying the any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  You should consider making use of a Swing [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of a `Thread` as you main game loop

Comment: And [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`

Comment: Examples  of the above suggestions from @MadProgrammer are shown in numerous examples on this site. You can search using `[Swing]` and/or `[Graphics]` tags.  Also check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Don't dispose of the supplied graphics context .  It's the same reference whether you cast or not.  If you want to dispose, then use `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();`